# Insert image to a SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert, sql-insert

I have used to bellow SQL query to create the 'Images' table where I want to store the images and other details.

```
CREATE TABLE Images (
        picid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        description VARCHAR(40),
        image BLOB,
        PRIMARY KEY (picid));
```

Then I used DML as below

```
INSERT INTO Images VALUES (NULL,'picture of a dog','D:\Images\one.jpg');
```

Queries are executed with out any error. But field viewer of image column does not contain the image. It gives the following for binary.
[image]

How can I solve my problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [LOAD_FILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) for that.

```
INSERT INTO Images VALUES (NULL,'picture of a dog', LOAD_FILE('D:\Images\one.jpg'));
```

If you don't MySQL will treat your `image` value just as a string and store it accordingly into the blob field.

Comment: Thank you. It worked with double slashes in the file path. ('D:\\Images\\one.jpg')

Comment: Yes, double slashes are specific to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Images VALUES (NULL,'picture of a dog','D:\Images\one.jpg');
```

This means you are storing the string `'D:\Images\one.jpg'` in the database.

Follow this link for details on how to proceed:
http://www.techcubetalk.com/tutorial-on-how-to-store-images-in-mysql-blob-field/

Cheers